# AWS cognito - how to refresh token in angular?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, token, amazon-cognito

I tried this code,

```
    const cognitoisp = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    const params = {
      AuthFlow: 'REFRESH_TOKEN',
      ClientId: '',
      UserPoolId: '',
      AuthParameters: {
        'REFRESH_TOKEN': ''
      }
    };

    cognitoisp.adminInitiateAuth(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('RefreshTokenError: ', err.stack);
      } else {
        console.log('RefreshTokenResponse: ', data);
      }
    });
```

but its not working. Or is there any other way to refresh token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `adminInitiateAuth` functions are reserved for people administering Cognito, you need to be using [initateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property):

```
const params = {
  AuthFlow: 'REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
  ClientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID!',
  AuthParameters: {
    'REFRESH_TOKEN': 'THE_REFRESH_TOKEN!'
  }
};

cognitoisp.initiateAuth(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('RefreshTokenError: ', err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log('RefreshTokenResponse: ', data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks thomasmichaelwallace. I tried this solution, butgetting this error - 'CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config'.

Comment: Are you providing `cognitoisp` with credentials? Like you did during the sign-in to get the initial tokens? (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js)

Comment: Auth.signIn(form.username, form.password).then(user => {
 }).catch(err => {
 });

Comment: Can you just confirm where `Auth` comes from- are you using `aws-amplify`?